# What is "SURGE CONFIRMATION REDIRECT URI" in Uber SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, uber-api

I need to add REDIRECT_URI in my Project to perform Uber login. Here is the code -

```
.setRedirectUri("<REDIRECT_URI>")
```

How to generate "REDIRECT_URI" in Uber Developer Dashboard?
Or let me know what is the exact format of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't generate the redirect URI, it's a URI that you set based on the server you are using to process OAuth. This URI will be used to redirect back to after an authorization. You can set a default URI in the developer dashboard:

[image: Dashboard: Auth Settings]

The [documentation explains](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/introduction#receive-redirect) this in more detail:

"Once the Uber user authenticates and authorizes your app, Uber will issue an HTTP 302 redirect to the redirect_uri passed in or the default when none is explicitly provided. On that redirect, you will receive an authorization code, which is single use and expires in 10 minutes."

`GET https://your-redirect-uri/?code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE`

Given the nature of your question, I would recommend to [check out this Introduction to Oauth2.0](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2)